# Providing that a method return an entity in an Interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Okay, I am trying to create an interface for my viewmodels that give a couple of mandatory methods and one property. Here it is.

```
interface IVmConvertible
{
    IVmConvertible Model { get; set; }
    Entity ConvertToModel(IVmConvertible target);
    IVmConvertible ConvertToViewModel(IVmConvertible target);
}
```

What I am having trouble with is abstracting my entity framework classes so that the `ConvertToModel` method's return type will account for any of my entities. My `ConvertToViewModel` method is fine because all my viewmodels implement this interface. I thought about creating an interface for all my entities but if I alter the auto generated code it will just be erased eachtime I change the database.

How can I abstract my `ConvertToModel` method to return any entity?

Comment: Perhaps generics would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution may or may not suit your needs.  It is something that we do here, and I am not sure I fully understand your requirements.  In these examples I assume a different interface for the `Entity` class to use, not `IVmConvertable`.  *I don't mention generics (which is probably a good way to do it, since that is already covered.*

**Manually**

1. Create a separate class file, like `EntitesPartialClasses.cs`
2. Add partial classes for each entity
3. Have the partial class implement the interface/etc (you could even derive!)

Class file:

```
public partial class MyEntityClass: IMyEntity {
     .... 
}
```

It would be best to explicitly implement the interface, so that a caller is forced to cast to it before being able to use the methods.  Since you expect the interface, this is no problem, but others won't be confused

```
public partial class MyEntityClass : IMyEntity {
     IMyEntity.MyMethod() { }
}
```

If you do derive from a base class, make that base class implement the interface in the same way.

**Modify the t4 template file**

I did this to add the documentation properties from the edmx file into the classes output.  Open the `Entities.tt` file (or whatever you have it called), and

1. Find the first loop (`foreach(var entity in ...`)
2. Find the class definition (starts with `<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#>`
3. Update the definition to add your custom interface

This may take a little work, since EF classes can also have another class as a base class.  I think the relevant change would look like this:

```
//-- original --
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#><#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class <#=code.Escape(entity)#><#=code.StringBefore(" : ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#>
```

{

```
//-- new ---
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#><#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class <#=code.Escape(entity)#>
    : IMyEntity <#=code.StringBefore(", ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#>
{
    // implement IMyEntity here, in the TT file
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is:

```
interface IVmConvertible<T>
{
    IVmConvertible Model { get; set; }
    T ConvertToModel(IVmConvertible target);
    IVmConvertible ConvertToViewModel(IVmConvertible target);
}
```

So your potential CarVm for Car entity would look like this:

```
public class CarVm : IVmConvertible<Car>
{
...
}
```

Other option is that you move from Database First approach to **Code First** approach. Enable migrations, make a snapshot of current database, and continue changing the database from the code instead. This way your entity classes will not be overrun, thus you can implement some other interface such as IEntity on them, and then use non-generic approach:

```
interface IVmConvertible
{
    IVmConvertible Model { get; set; }
    IEntity ConvertToModel(IVmConvertible target);
    IVmConvertible ConvertToViewModel(IVmConvertible target);
}
```